# toString method of a linear equation

Tags: java, tostring, equation

I am trying to represent an equation in this format: "a = bx + c"

- If b is 0, it should return “a = c”.
- If c is 0, then it should return “a = bx”
- Also, when c is negative it should not return something like "5 = 8x + -7"
- And when b=1, it should not show the coefficient of x.

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Seems like each of those conditions that you've listed will end up as some kind of `if` statement in your code.  You've already done the hard part - working out what all the various cases should be.  Now have a go at writing some code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just construct the string step by step in a StringBuilder:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a).append(" = ");

    if (b > 1 || b < -1) {
        sb.append(b);
    } else if (b == -1) {
        sb.append('-');
    }

    if (b != 0) {
        sb.append('x ');

        if (c > 0) {
            sb.append('+');
        } else if (c < 0) {
            sb.append('-');
        }

        sb.append(' ');
    }

    sb.append(Math.abs(c));

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: `return` statement is missing.

Comment: @saka1029 huh, I went through all the trouble and forgot the punchline. Thanks for noticing! Edited and fixed.

Comment: Is `b` necessarily an integer?  I was thinking of these variables as floating point, and I notice that you've made values of `b` between -1 and 1 disappear into thin air.